# how to turn a rescue kernel into a working one?

Tags: centos, centos7, kernel-panic

A `yum update`  today made one of my CentOS 7 servers unusable: there is kernel panic as soon as the boot starts. I tried to start previous kernels from GRUB but all of them crash the same way. I even tried to install the latest 4.1 kernel, it also crashes with

```
kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs
```

There is an exception, though: the last line on GRUB which is the "Rescue kernel". This one boots fine, I can login on the console (there are no error messages displayed).

I tried to reinstall the kernels (`yum reinstall kernel`, `yum remove kernel ; yum update`) - same crash.
There is about 200 MB left on `/boot`.

Where should I go from there? (short of reinstalling the OS)

**EDIT:** further information following comments

This is a physical machine, the filesystems are not encrypted

```
# rpm -qa kernel
kernel-3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64

# df -T
Filesystem                       Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_euextscan-lv_root ext4      51475068 17826932  31010312  37% /
devtmpfs                         devtmpfs  16347896        0  16347896   0% /dev
tmpfs                            tmpfs     16367276        0  16367276   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            tmpfs     16367276    16932  16350344   1% /run
tmpfs                            tmpfs     16367276        0  16367276   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                        ext4        487652   179742    278214  40% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_euextscan-lv_home ext4     507841520 11176144 470845424   3% /home

# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_euextscan
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               557.88 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              142818
  Alloc PE / Size       142818 / 557.88 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               JOZX35-8T48-Yd10-wcta-wfSR-Fpf0-Hfkk1S

cat /boot/grub/grub.conf
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_euextscan-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sdb
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS Linux (3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_euextscan-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=fr LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
title CentOS Linux (4.1.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64) 7 (Core)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-4.1.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_euextscan-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=fr LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
title CentOS Linux (3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_euextscan-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=fr LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64.img
title CentOS Linux 7 Rescue 3df14aca2793db41f468b5f800000019 (3.10.0-123.9.2.el7.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-0-rescue-3df14aca2793db41f468b5f800000019 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_euextscan-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=fr LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_swap rd_LVM_LV=vg_euextscan/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-0-rescue-3df14aca2793db41f468b5f800000019.img
```

Comment: do a "df -h"... do you have free space left on /boot?

Comment: Sorry,  I forgot about that : yes, there is space left on `/boot` (about 200 MB)

Comment: More information is required: physical or virtual? how is your root filesystem configured? is there hardware or software RAID involved? LUKS encryption? have you already tried to inspect the filesystems from the rescue kernel?

Comment: Also, a full grub configuration and list of disks/filesystems would surely help

Comment: Did you revert to an older kernel? By default yum keeps several around, `yum list kernel`, pick a previous one and install it with `yum install kernel-<version>`.

Comment: @Brian: as I mentioned, none of the previous kernels worked (they crash the same way), except for the rescue one.

Comment: Where did you get a `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file from? You should not have this file at all. The system should be using grub 2 to boot.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: the file is straight from the server, without modifications.

Comment: That's just it, _it should not exist_. Someone has done something very strange to your installation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: The [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader.html) states however that *GRUB 2 reads its configuration from the /boot/grub2/grub.cfg file on traditional BIOS-based machines and from the /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg file on UEFI machines.*

Comment: That's exactly my point!